# rubygems error installing rails

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I get this error when trying to install ruby gems on my amazon instance. Can anyone explain?

```
ubuntu@ip-myinstance:~$ sudo apt-get install rubygems

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package rubygems is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  ruby

E: Package 'rubygems' has no installation candidate
```

I didn't understand that message. I was following directions from http://www.frontcoded.com/rails-on-amazon-ec2-ubuntu.html which says to do that. Also I tried

```
which rubygems
```

And that came out blank. If possible I would like to take down this question to stop the negative votes. Thank you.

Comment: Did you read the message from apt-get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to install the wrong package. In modern Ruby, rubygems come as part of it. The message you got also says so.

Even if there were a problem on the server side, not being able to download something through apt-get has nothing to do with whether rubygems site is down.

The message you got, which gives you an alternative suggestion, indicates that the relevant site (apt-get) is not down.

You can check the status of certain websites by using services like [this](http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/rubygems.org.html).